# Converting List to Vector using Tidyverse

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, stringr, purrr

Here is a simple example from "R for Data Science":

```
df <- tribble(
  ~x1,
  "a,b,c",
  "d,e,f,g"
)
```

Now I can create a list-column like this:

```
df <- df %>%
  mutate(x2 = stringr::str_split(x1, ","))
```

Now the data looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 2 × 2
       x1        x2
    <chr>    <list>
1   a,b,c <chr [3]>
2 d,e,f,g <chr [4]>
```

Here is the question: If I only have x2, how can I recover x1 from it?

`unnest()` does not work because it changes the shape of the data.

Comment: You can use `sapply(df$x2, toString)` to paste the vector in the list to get back a string.

Comment: Thanks. The tidyverse equivalent will be: 

    df <- df %>% 
      mutate(x3 = map_chr(x2, toString))

It produces:

    # A tibble: 2 × 3
           x1        x2         x3
        <chr>    <list>      <chr>
    1   a,b,c <chr [3]>    a, b, c
    2 d,e,f,g <chr [4]> d, e, f, g

Nice!

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
df %>% 
  mutate(x1_new = map_chr(x2, paste, collapse = ','))
```

(I assume you have loaded package `purrr` since you've mentioned `tidyverse`)

Comment: Nice. So both toString() and paste() can do this. Thanks.

Comment: If you enter `toString.default` (no `?` or `()`'s) in a console, you'll see the default implementation is `paste(x, collapse = ", ")`

Comment: @hrbrmstr that is true. but this is kind of function that takes away too much freedom (`sep` and `collapse`) compared to how little it does

Comment: Totally agree @JanKislinger. I was making the note abt what `toString()` does for the OP's edification. Your way is better, tho `paste0` wld prbly be most appropriate in this usage.

Answer (score 2):

Very nice. Also, within the tidyverse:

```
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(x3 = map_chr(x2, stringr::str_c, collapse = ','))
df
```

also works.

Comment: i'd strongly suggest avoiding the `stringr` crutch and going directly to `stringi` functions that it wraps. one less function call and loads more ultimate power.